# Django template - get object's choice field text

Tags: python, django, templates, django-models, choicefield

This is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    DOP = 1
    PPP = 2
    contract_choices = (
        (DOP, 'always'),
        (PPP, 'sometimes'),
    )

    contract = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices = contract_choices)
    ...
```

I need `contract` field value in my template:

```
{% for person in persons %}
{{ person.get_contract_display }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives me '1' (or '2') instead of 'always' (or 'sometimes'). How can i get that string **text** instead of integer value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CharField but your choice values are ints. Use strings there instead:

```
DOP = '1'
PPP = '2'
```

Comment: Sharp eye you have! I can't believe i have missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    contract_choices = (
        ('DOP', 'always'),
        ('PPP', 'sometimes'),
    )

    contract = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices = contract_choices)
```

And then you can access keys:

```
{{ person.contract_choices }}
```

returns: 'DOP' or 'PPP'

Or if you want values:

```
{{ person.get_contract_choices_dysplay }}
```

returns: 'always' or 'sometimes'

### EDIT: Proper way according to Django's documentation

Integer type in DB might be better in you case. You can create subclass of Django's `models.IntegerChoices`

```py
class Person(models.Model):

    class ContractType(models.IntegerChoices):
        DOP = 0, 'always'
        PPP = 1, 'sometimes'

    contract = models.IntegerField(
        "Contract", choices=ContractType.choices, default=0
    )
```

and get it in template as `{{ person.get_contract_display }}`

Please refer to [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) in Django docs for more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).